# Is it possible to customize the style and text of a custom label in salesforce?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I need to show an error message on the helper page, where the first word of the message is bold.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please show your code so we can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customize the style or text of a custom label in salesforce, all you can do is use CSS to customize it in the UI.
Only language translation is possible with the custom label as an out of the box functionality.